How to use nestjs guard with websocket
I have a NestJS server up and running, and I'm using the default WebSocket adapter (socket.io).
I've implemented global guards and interceptors that work perfectly with my HTTP requests, but for some reason, they don't seem to apply to WebSocket events.
Here's what I've done:

Set up global guards using app.useGlobalGuards() in the main.ts.

Registered global interceptors using app.useGlobalInterceptors().


These work as expected for HTTP routes, but when handling WebSocket
requests, the global guards and interceptors are not triggered.
My questions are:
Why aren't the global guards and interceptors being triggered for WebSocket events?
Is there a different way to apply guards or interceptors specifically to WebSocket requests in NestJS?
